# Can't seem to get output in the transcript [Smalltalk]

Tags: oop, smalltalk

I'm currently working on an assignment done in smalltalk and while I'm just getting the grasp of the language, I'm a bit stumped and am looking for some direction.

Normally to print to the transcript in Pharo I would use:

```
print   
    Transcript show: 'Hello my name is: ' , self theName printString; cr
```

It seems that if I put a conditional in the beginning such as

```
printNew
      (age < 50) ifTrue: [ Transcript show: 'Hello my name is: ', self theName, 'and I am old' printString ]; cr
```

I can't seem to get the printNew method to print to the transcript.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: So what is the value of `age`?

Answer (score 2):

Let me format your expression to better understand it:

```
(age < 50)
  ifTrue: [
    Transcript show:
      'Hello my name is: ', self theName, 'and I am old' printString];
     cr
```

looks like

```
(age < 5) ifTrue: [<something>]; cr
```

which in turn has the structure of

```
(age < 5) msg; cr
```

because in Smalltalk `ifTrue: [<something>]` is nothing but a message. Do you see the mistake now? The cascade symbol `;` sends first `msg` to the `Boolean` expression `(age < 5)` and then sends it `cr` which it does not understand. Just fix the transposition between `]` and `; cr`:

```
(age < 50)
  ifTrue: [
    Transcript show:
      'Hello my name is: ', self theName, 'and I am old' printString;
      cr]
```

Note also that a better way to write the same is

```
(age < 50)
  ifTrue: [
    Transcript
      show: 'Hello my name is: ';
      show: self theName;
      show: ' and I am old' printString;
      cr]
```

Why? Because this way you do not create two intermediate strings by concatenating the three parts of your text.

Finally note that because of precedence rules you don't need the parentheses around `age < 50`

BTW, if you are under `50` you are not old!